# Graylog + Elasticsearch - How to query by regex with the following pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog

Graylog uses Elasticsearch as rep, so I'm tagging this as Elasticsearch also.

So, I have the following message pattern:

> DURATION | GET > /usuarios/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/cartoes/simplificados > 200 em 1060,7302 ms

and I would like to search for the durations ABOVE 1000 ms, so I came up with this regex:

`DURATION \| GET > \/usuarios.*[0-9]{4,},[0-9]*.*ms`

and, although it works perfectly on online tools, graylog doesn't return anything. So I changed it to:

`[0-9]{4,},[0-9]*.*ms` and still nothing. Next I tested `em 1060.*` and also nothing!!!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

`Environment:prod AND "DURATION | GET > /usuarios/" AND message:/.*([0-9]{4,}.[0-9]{4}).*/`